# stopping a function from another function

Tags: php, function

IN PHP, Is it possible that I could stop a function from an internal function?, for example

```
function_1(){
   ......
function2();
....
}
```

Can I stop function1 using a sentence in function2 but avoiding stopping the whole script?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say "stop"?

Comment: like "return false" but I can not put return function2(); Stop the execution.

Comment: If you are doing this as a part of verification or validation, you can throw an exception and have some outer function catch it.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this if you capture the return value of your second function.

```
function my_first_function() {
  // some code
  if( !my_second_function() ) {
     return;
  }
}

function my_second_function() {
  return false;
}

my_first_function();
```

Of course you need to modify it to meet you needs but that should get you started.

Comment: That is the problema, I can not modify the structure, I just can insert functions.

Comment: If you can't change the code, then you can't do what you're trying to do.

Comment: I see, have a look at the goto operator (http://us.php.net/goto). I never used it myself and I don't recommend using it because I believe that if you end up using it your code is probably not engineered properly, but that might be what you are looking for. Is there a reason why you can only add functions and not modify the code?

Comment: `goto` won't work.  From the documentation: "The target label must be within the same file and context, meaning that you cannot jump out of a function or method"

Comment: I don't think there is another way to do it than the way I posted above and like Charles said, goto won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [RunKit extension](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-rename.php), which lets you redefined/rename functions. By default it only allows this to be done on user-defined functions, but there's a php.ini setting to enable it for internal functions as well.

That would let you do something like:

```
runkit_function_rename('print', 'internal_print');
function print(...) {
   echo 'welcome to my own implementation of print';
}
```

However, messing with internal functions can basically break PHP, so use at your own risk.

Comment: that is what i need but the problem is that not all erver has PECL!!

Comment: It'd be about the only practical option, though. If you need to disable a function like this, then you should rethink your security model.